# How to change Learning rate in Tensorflow dependent on number of batches and epochs?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, callback, tensorflow2.0, learning-rate

Is there a possibility to implement the following scenario with Tensorflow:

In the first N batches, the learning rate should be increased from 0 to 0.001. After this number of batches has been reached, the learning rate should slowly decrease from 0.001 to 0.00001 after each epoch.

How can I combine this combination in a callback? Tensorflow offers the tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler and the callback functions on_train_batch_begin() or on_train_batch_end(). But I will not come to a common combination of these callbacks.

Can someone give me an approach how to create such a combined callback that depends on the number of batches and epochs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something *like* this would work. I didn't test this and I didn't try to perfect it...but the pieces are there so that you can get it working how you like.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
import numpy as np

class LRSetter(Callback):
    
    def __init__(self, start_lr=0, middle_lr=0.001, end_lr=0.00001, 
                 start_mid_batches=200, end_epochs=2000):
        
        self.start_mid_lr = np.linspace(start_lr, middle_lr, start_mid_batches)
        #Not exactly right since you'll have gone through a couple epochs
        #but you get the picture
        self.mid_end_lr = np.linspace(middle_lr, end_lr, end_epochs) 
        
        self.start_mid_batches = start_mid_batches
        
        self.epoch_takeover = False
        
    def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
    
        if batch < self.start_mid_batches:
            tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, self.start_mid_lr[batch])
        else:
            self.epoch_takeover = True

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch):
        if self.epoch_takeover:
            tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, self.mid_end_lr[epoch])
```